# Does Dart support parameterized unit tests?

Tags: dart

I would like to run a Dart test which is repeated with a set of inputs and expected outputs, similar to what is possible with JUnit.

I wrote the following test to achieve similar behavior but the problem is that event if all the test outputs are computed incorrectly, the test will only fail once:

```
import 'package:test/test.dart';

void main() {
  test('formatDay should format dates correctly', () async {
    var inputsToExpected = {
      DateTime(2018, 11, 01): "Thu 1",
      ...
      DateTime(2018, 11, 07): "Wed 7",
      DateTime(2018, 11, 30): "Fri 30",
    };

    // When
    var inputsToResults = inputsToExpected.map((input, expected) =>
        MapEntry(input, formatDay(input))
    );

    // Then
    inputsToExpected.forEach((input, expected) {
      expect(inputsToResults[input], equals(expected));
    });
  });
}
```

The reason I want to use parameterized tests, is so that I can achieve the following behavior in my test:

- Write only one test
- Test `n` different inputs/outputs
- Fail `n` times if all `n` tests are broken

Answer (score 73, accepted):

Dart's `test` package is smart in that it is not trying to be too clever. The `test` function is just a function that you call, and you can call it anywhere, even inside a loop or another function call.
So, for your example, you can do something like:

```
group("formatDay should format dates correctly:", () {
  var inputsToExpected = {
    DateTime(2018, 11, 01): "Thu 1",
    ...
    DateTime(2018, 11, 07): "Wed 7",
    DateTime(2018, 11, 30): "Fri 30",
  };
  inputsToExpected.forEach((input, expected) {
    test("$input -> $expected", () {
      expect(formatDay(input), expected);
    });
  });
});
```

The only important thing to remember is that all the calls to `test` should happen synchronously when the `main` function is called, so no calling it inside asynchronous functions. If you need time to set something up before running the test, do so in a `setUp` instead.

You can also create a helper function, and drop the map entirely (this is what I usually do):

```
group("formatDay should format dates correctly:", () {
  void checkFormat(DateTime input, String expected) {
    test("$input -> $expected", () {
      expect(formatDay(input), expected);
    });
  }
  checkFormat(DateTime(2018, 11, 01), "Thu 1");
  ...
  checkFormat(DateTime(2018, 11, 07), "Wed 7");
  checkFormat(DateTime(2018, 11, 30), "Fri 30");
});
```

Here each call of checkFormat introduces a new test with its own name, and each of them can fail individually.

Comment: Novel approach 

Comment: Btw. to have more verbose output for individual parameters, you can nest `group` (you cannot do that with `test`).

Comment: Very cool. I wanted to test different implementations of an abstract class (a key-value store) but reuse the same test cases. This answer helped a lot.