# flutter widget test: is there any way to write Data driven testcase

Tags: flutter, testing, widget, data-driven

if i have two similar test（widget test case）, is there some way to simplify the test code, maybe like Data driven test（use such as python Decorator)?

Comment: You can try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53103300/does-dart-support-parameterized-unit-tests